# foreach in TikZ and node names

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am encountering the following problem with this code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\tkzAngleResult{-145}
\node[coordinate](v_B)at (-145:5){};
\path [draw] let \p1=(v_B), \n1={veclen((\x1,\y1))} in 
    foreach[count=\i]\frac in{0,0.1,...,1.1}{%
        ($ (0,0)!\frac!(-10,3)$)node[coordinate](debut\i){}--++({\tkzAngleResult-(\tkzAngleResult+270)/11*\i}:\n1)node[coordinate](fin\i){}
    }
;
\foreach\i in {1,..,11}{%
    \draw(debut\i)--(fin\i);
}
\draw[blue](0,0)--(-10,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields as a result an error as Latex doesn't know any shape named `debut`, although what it should receive would be `debut1`, `debut2` ... etc because of the use of `foreach` with `\i` as a variable.

Does anybody knows why it behaves like this?

Comment: you are missing a dot: `\foreach\i in {1,...,11}`. If you add the third dot it compiles fine.

Comment: the nasty little details that can ruin a compilation... thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code was missing a dot in `\foreach\i in {1,..,11}`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\tkzAngleResult{-145}
\node[coordinate](v_B)at (-145:5){};
\path [draw] let \p1=(v_B), \n1={veclen((\x1,\y1))} in 
    foreach[count=\i]\frac in{0,0.1,...,1.1}{%
        ($ (0,0)!\frac!(-10,3)$)node[coordinate](debut\i){}--++({\tkzAngleResult-(\tkzAngleResult+270)/11*\i}:\n1)node[coordinate](fin\i){}
    }
;
\foreach\i in {1,...,11}{%
    \draw(debut\i)--(fin\i);
}
\draw[blue](0,0)--(-10,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]